# Storing a variable which is reset every time you come to reference - PHP

Tags: php

This is more of a general programming question as opposed to a PHP question, however the PHP language is the one I am using current.

I will show you a dilemma which I am having and I not found a solution as of yet; will be interesting to see the answer.

Full file (only short, jQuery is loading this in):

```
<?php
    require_once('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
?>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><img id="quoteOne" src="http://www.1.co.uk/wp-content/themes/1/images/quote1.png">
    <span><?php
        query_posts(array(
            'cat' => 39,
            'order' => 'ASC', // ASC
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'showposts' => 1,
            ));
        $wp_query->is_archive = true; $wp_query->is_home = false;
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        the_content();
        //the_id();
        endwhile; endif;
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['i'] = the_id();
        $prev = $_SESSION['i'];
        //echo $_SESSION['i'];
        //$_SESSION['i']++;
    ?>
    <a href="#" style="color: #86a53e;" id="nextQu">NEXT QUOTE</span>
    </span>
```

PHP (code in question):

```
// the_id() returns current id of post
session_start();
$_SESSION['i'] = the_id();
$prev = $_SESSION['i'];
```

The objective of this snippet is to check that the current id does not equal the previous id (to prevent duplicates showing and looking like nothing is happening). I need to be able to perform something like;

```
if($previous == $current){
    // try again
}
```

I cannot find a way to store it without it being reset every time. Is there a way of programming to do this?

This file is loaded via: (a separate file)

```
$('#testimonialContent').load('http://www.1.co.uk/wp-content/themes/1/testimonialPull.php');
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're asking, but is this what you want?

```
session_start();
$prev = isset($_SESSION['i']) ? $_SESSION['i'] : null;
$_SESSION['i'] = the_id();

if ($prev == $_SESSION['i'])
{
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: I don't often see the `?` in syntax so I don't fully understand that line, however I believe the `isset()` method could be a potential solution